# Oauth2, native apps and token stealing

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using OAuth2 authorization mechanism for my mobile app to access my resource server. I have defined client which has its secret, name `mobile_client` and uses Authorization Code Grant to obtain Refresh Token. I also have one user `user@app.pl` who is using my app on two mobile phones. I noticed an issue with token stealing.

The scenario looks like this:

```
                                                +---------------+
 (Phone 1)----------- Refresh Token1----------->| Authorization |
 (Phone 1)<--- Access Token1+Refresh Token2-----|    Server     |
                                                +---------------+
                                  +----------+ 
 (Phone 1)---- Access Token1 ---->| Resource |
 (Phone 1)-- Protected Resource --|  Server  |
                                  +----------+ 
                                                +---------------+
 (Phone 2)---------- Refresh Token2 ----------->| Authorization |
 (Phone 2)<--- Access Token2+Refresh Token3-----|    Server     |
                                                +---------------+
                                 +----------+ 
 (Phone 1)---- Access Token1 --->| Resource |
 (Phone 1)<- 401 TOKEN EXPIRED!  |  Server  |
                                 +----------+
```

It looks like `user@app.pl` on Phone 1 and Phone 2 received the same Refresh Token from my Authorization Server for calls with the same app and username. This in the end caused that the second call refreshed Access Token on the Phone 1 as well.

Is that a proper behavior of Authorization Server?

I use Spring Security Oauth2 2.3.3.RELEASE and Spring Security 5.1.0.RELEASE

**Edit**

As I see in Google oauth2 specification they provide more refresh tokens per user so this should be configured somehow in Spring.

> There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per
>   client. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token
>   automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without warning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating the access tokens using the refresh tokens created from same Authorization Code, I would say this is expected scenario since revoking the old access token while refreshing the access token ensures security.

Did you try using access tokens from 2 different Authorization Codes ?